# How it is storing more index values in it?

Tags: r, probability-theory

While running a for loop, I came across a problem:

```
d = data.frame(X = rbeta(20000, 2, 5))

k = numeric(10000)
for (i in 1:10000){
  j = sample(d$X, 100)
  k[i] = mean(j)
}
```

I have two questions

1. How the shapes (2, 5) works in **rbeta**
2. Here when the mean(j) (which has 100 samples in it) is stored in k then why k when printing showing 10000 values to me. I hope you understand my question

Comment: 1. This is described in `rbeta` help. Did you look into it? 2. You define `k` as numeric vector of length 10000, then populate it using a for loop over i from 1 to 10000 - no wonder it shows you 10000 values.

Answer (score 0):

1) From the documentation of `rbeta` (see `?rbeta`), I think the shapes : `shape1` and `shape2` correspond to the `alpha` and `beta` parameter of the beta distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution for details and distribution graphs depending on the choice of parameters).

2) When your write

```r
k = numeric(10000)
```

If you call `k` you will see a numeric vector of length 10000. Then in your for loop you assign 10000 sample mean (out of 100) to the 10000 values of k.
If you want to look at a specific value in vector k you can do so using :

```r
k[1] # or any index integer needed
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `?rbeta` can guide you to understand `shape1` and `shape2`
2. I guess what you expect might be a `for-loop` like below:

```
l <- list()
for (i in 1:10000){
  j = sample(d$X, 100)
  l <- c(l,list(K = mean(j), J = j)) 
}
```